# Updating $scope for ng-repeat after service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seperated out my controllers & services into modules, and on a form submit,  I am trying to get data from a service and then set it in the scope, but I'm having trouble getting the view to update with the new data. I have gone through other questions with similar problems but I can't seem to get it working. The view updates fine from the Search.get() function, but not from the $scope.submitFilterForm function.

I'm trying to update like this:

```
$scope.searchDetails = results;
```

This is my code at the moment:

**SearchCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('SearchCtrl', []).controller('SearchController', function($scope, $http, Page, Search) {

    $scope.pageClass = 'page-search';
    $scope.showContent = false;
    $scope.searchDetails = [];

    Search.get().success(function(searchResults) {
        $scope.searchDetails = searchResults;
        Page.setTitle('Search');
        $scope.showContent = true;
    });

    $scope.submitFilterForm = function(isValid) {
        if (isValid) {

            Search.filterByPostcode($scope.postcode, $scope.searchradius).success(function(results) {
                console.log('results', results);
                $scope.searchDetails = results;
            });

        }
    }

});
```

**SearchService.js**

```
angular.module('SearchService', []).factory('Search', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {

        get: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/places');
        },

        filterByPostcode: function(postcode, searchradius) {
            return $http.get('/api/filter-by-postcode/'+postcode+'/'+searchradius);
        }

    }

}]);
```

**search.html**

```
<div class="places-list" ng-show="showContent">
    <div class="places-list-item" ng-repeat="place in searchDetails">
        <a href="/place/{{place.id}}">{{place.place_name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have the template above set up in appRoutes.js like so:

```
$routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/search', {
            title: 'Search',
            templateUrl: '/partials/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchController'
        })

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: in the search.html why is there a ng-model attribute on the repeating div?

Comment: Well spotted. I added that by accident, it's removed now.

Comment: have you tried to use `$scope.$apply()` after you set the results in `submitFilterForm` function

Comment: Yes, and I get the following error in the console : Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: As your not using something outside of angular to get the data, your using $http to make the call, $scope.$apply shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Can you see the scope in chrome Batarang?
If not try this in the console.. 

`angular.element($('.places-list')[0]).scope().searchDetails`

Comment: In batarang I have scope 003 and 004 which look the same, and when I submit the form, only 003 updates. 003 has the correct data in it but the page still uses 004.

Comment: I've moved the ng-controller attribute higher in the DOM and removed it from the routeProvider and it seems to work OK now.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?